# How to approximate a normal distribution?

Tags: normal-distribution, approximation

Suppose I have two random variables $a$ and $b$. $a$ follows a normal distribution of parameters $u_1, s_1$. $b$ follows a normal distribution of parameters $u_2, s_2$. $u_1$ and $u_2$ are the expectations. $s_1$ and $s_2$ are the variances. If I randomly generate a number from $a$ with probability $p_a$, from $b$ with probability $1-p_a$.

I know the expectation will be $$u_1p_1 + u_2(1-p_1).$$ What about the variance? Can I use some method to approximate it?

Comment: Is the way you pick $a$ or $b$  independent from them?

Comment: yes,independent

Answer (score 0):

Let you new random variable be $c$. Then $\mbox{Var}(c)=E(c^2)-(E(c))^2$ and you already know $E(c)$, so that leaves only $E(c^2)$ to be found.

Now it is either in your notes or text (and if not easily proven) that:
$E(c^2)=p_1E(a^2)+(1-p_1)E(b^2)$ and the two expectations on the right can be found from the means and variances of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: thx a lot! I have another question:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1251319/what-is-the-distribution-of-max-of-some-normaldistributions